# Help! Joomla Templates!

Tags: joomla

I need to make this design: http://www.stephburningham.com/lmg/
into a joomla template but I've never made a joomla template before and the tutorials are so complex!

Can anyone start me off?

Thanks a lot,
Steph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing would be to break the page down into areas of content, such as leftnav, header, footer, maincontent. Take the HTML and remove the content, leaving only the structure. Take one of the existing templates (Beez), copy it and rename it (and in the template.xml file).

Add your new module positions to the XML file and then start populating it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no other way than reading [Joomla's tutorials and documentation](http://www.compassdesigns.net/joomla-tutorials/joomla-template-tutorial) on the web. And after reading some tutorials about templates, learn the [differences between Modules, Components and plugins](http://www.ultijoomla.com/blog/Joomla-Components-Modules-and-Plugins.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might be best off to take a commericial theme like those available at [Rocket Theme](http://www.rockettheme.com) and adapting your design into it (they have a good high performance free theme).  This way you get the benefits of your look and feel, but in a first class theme that will cause you very little compatibility issues across browsers and offer substantial features out of the box.